# Drag and Drop File Uploads from Chrome Downloads Bar

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I have successfully implemented drag and drop file uploads for a web application using HTML 5. I listen for the drop event, then grab file data from the event.dataTransfer property.

For all intents and purposes, it works exactly like dropzone.js:

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

For some reason, though, I'm unable to drag and drop files from the Chrome downloads bar.

[image]

The dragenter, dragover, and dragleave events fire, but no drop event fires. This can be reliably reproduced using the dropzone.js demo website.

Why?

Comment: Apparently dropzone.js (and your code) aren't handling DnD events correctly then.  It works just fine in the upload library I maintain, [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  You can try for yourself on the home page by using the live demos.  Fine Uploader's DnD code can be found in the library's [dnd.js source file](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/client/js/dnd.js) for reference.

Comment: Cool I'll check it out

Comment: This seems like a Chrome bug. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234931&

Answer (score 9):

The trick is that by default, the `dropEffect` attribute of the `event.dataTransfer` passed to `dragover` is set to `'none'` by default. You'll need to detect this, and set it to either copy or move, depending on the use case.

For me, setting it to copy worked. I didn't have to do anything to the `drop` event. Just a modification to the `dragover` event.

Here's what I did:

```
// The dragover event
function onDragover(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent) {
        e = e.originalEvent;
    }

    if (!e.dataTransfer) {
        return;
    }

    // Code I added begins here
    var b = e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed;

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = ('move' === b || 'linkMove' === b) ? 'move' : 'copy';
    // Code I added ends here

    this.$el.addClass('dragging');

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Some fun reading: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html